# "You don't have permission to access" laser.bag

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was trying to follow the laser_pipeline tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/laser_pipeline/Tutorials/IntroductionToWorkingWithLaserScannerData

I saved the link for laser.bag (located here: http://vault.willowgarage.com/wgdata1/vol1/wiki_docs/laser_pipeline/laser.bag) but it said that I didn't have permission to access it. From the bag file: "You don't have permission to access /wgdata1/vol1/wiki_docs/laser_pipeline/laser.bag on this server." Is this just an outdated link?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206712/%22you-don%27t-have-permission-to-access%22-laser.bag/) by [nbanyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/19003/nbanyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2015-04-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah, that's an outdated link to an unmaintained Willow Garage server. Someone will probably need to recreate that bag file.

If someone does, recreate it appropriately contact me (@tfoote) and I can place it on download.ros.org

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/19003/nbanyk/) on 2015-06-24**:
Looks like there is access to the bag file here: http://answers.ros.org/question/211361/unable-to-download-laserbag/